# AngularFontAwesome will not display in table with injected Html through Pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, font-awesome, angular-pipe

I have the following Pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'transferStatusTransformation'
})
export class TransferStatusTransformationPipe implements PipeTransform {

  private mappedTransferStatus: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>();

  constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {

  }

  transform(value: TransferMetaViewModel): any {
    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.buildStatusHtml(value));
  }

  private buildStatusHtml(value: TransferMetaViewModel): string {
    let htmlConcatenatedString = '';

    if (value.IsDevianceTracked && !value.IsDevianceVariance) {
      //deviance linked. No Variance. Green link
      htmlConcatenatedString += "<fa name='link'></fa>";
    }

    if (value.IsDevianceTracked && value.IsDevianceVariance && value.IsDevianceLinkBroken) {
      //deviance linked. Broken. Red broken link
      htmlConcatenatedString += "<fa name='unlink'></fa>";
    }

    if (value.IsCorrection) {
      //Is Correction transfer
      htmlConcatenatedString += "<fa name='clipboard-list'></fa>";
    }

    if (value.HasCorrection) {
      //Has correction
      htmlConcatenatedString += "<fa name='clipboard-list'></fa>";
    }

    if (value.IsReversed) {
      //reversed
      htmlConcatenatedString += "<fa name='backward'></fa>";
    }

    return htmlConcatenatedString;
  }
}
```

I use the `Pipe` as follow:

```
<table class="table table-sm table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Primary Account</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Secondary Account</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of results.Data">
        <td>{{item.Id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.PrimaryAccountName}}</td>
        <td>{{getTransferType(item.TransferTypeId)}}</td>
        <td>{{item.PartnerAccountName}}</td>
        <td>{{item.TransferDate}}</td>
        <td><span [innerHtml]="item.TransferMeta | transferStatusTransformation"></span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

When I inspect the element in Chrome, I can see the `<fa></fa>` tag has been added, as can be seen below:

[image: inspectedImage]

I am using 'FontAwesome' icons elsewhere in the application, and they render fine.  So it is not an issue with the `FontAwesomeModule` not being imported.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lkjkmt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) is the Stackblitz.

Why is the FontAwesome not rendering?

Comment: Will you be able to reproduce this with stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lkjkmt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Your stackblitz link doesn't have font-awesome dependency. Could you please add it too? Or post your package.json as well as module code where you have imported `FortAwesomeModule`

Comment: I have updated it, please check :-)

Comment: I think there's an **[ongoing issue](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/issues/72)** with the library. But there is one suggestion suggested, using `ngOnChanges`. You could try that. But the best case would be to use font-awesome css and then use the plain html instead of angular library.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that due to the way Angular lifecycle works, I will need to manually call ngOnChanges()

Comment: I agree.. :) Happy coding..